# Sound Broken on Thinkpad X250 on Early March 2015 15.05 Pre-Release Daily Build

Tags: sound, lubuntu, thinkpad

*TL;DR* Installed the Mar 8 lubuntu 15.04 daily build and sound doesn't work at all, but overall better than a stable release. What can I try?

I'm using the newly released Thinkpad X250 which has one of the 15 W Broadwell processors. I've read posts detailing the various steps involved in getting vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 working with the laptop so I decided to give the current state of 15.04, especially because I'm interested in getting the the newest stable graphic drivers for the graphics integrated into the processor.

I downloaded the Friday March 6 2015 lubuntu daily for the 15.04 (http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/) 64 bit image and the installation went very well, except that full disk encryption with LUKS failed, citing some swap space that may allow for partial recovery of the encryption key. The freshly installed operating system worked great - the linux version of Team Fortress 2 ran at respectable frame rates at settings i found acceptable, the trackpad works well enough (no side scrolling), trackpoint works, wireless lan works like a dream, and brightness changing buttons work as expected.

The main problems are that the trackpad buttons are mapped to different (and useless) keypresses and that **the sound doesn't work at all**. Is there anything I can try to enable sound on the machine other than hoping for a fix via `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post by Adam Olsen](http://vimtips.org/2015/02/20/ubuntu-1410-and-lenovo-thinkpad-x250/) describes the most common issue with getting the Thinkpad X250 working with a recent Ubuntu version. I assume that most of the problems are still present and solve the same way in the upcoming 15.04 version:

Quoting inline:

---

> To make this work, create a file at `/lib/firmware/x250.fw` with the following contents:
>
> ```
> [codec]
> 0x10ec0292 0x17aa2226 0
> [pincfg]
> 0x16 0x21211010
> 0x19 0x21a11010
> ```
>
> ... then, create a file called `/etc/modprobe.d/hda-intel.conf` with the following contents:

```
options snd-hda-intel patch=x250.fw,x250.fw,x250.fw
```

> Reboot, and the audio port on your dock should work. I imagine the process is the same for any of 2015 thinkpads. With each thinkpad, the only number that changes is the second one under the `[codec]` heading (in this case, `0x17aa2226`). That information can be found by downloading this script: http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh, and running it via `bash alsa-info.sh` as root. Search for `0x17aa` in the output, and you'll find the other half of the number you need.